# Android limit CALL_PHONE permission to avoid hidden calls

Tags: android, permissions, phone-call

The Android docs for the `CALL_PHONE` permission reads:
"Allows an application to initiate a phone call without going through the Dialer
user interface for the user to confirm the call being placed."
Also this message is prompted to the user when he installs the app. 
Reading that the application may start hidden calls can possibly discourage installation for some users.

Since my app does NOT start hidden calls, I wonder if there is a way to limit this behaviour, possibly with a more strict permission, to avoid displaying that dreadful message to the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my corrected solution:

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);  
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 1234));
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

This doesn't require any permissions and just open the dialer. Should be exactly that what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. There are 2 permissions associated with phone calls (`CALL_PHONE`, `CALL_PRIVILEGED`) with `CALL_PHONE` being the less restrict one. Google Play will always show that discouraging description for any application holding these permissions.

If this permission is really important for your application, leave it as it is.  But opening the dialer instead of calling is a much better option for the user experience (In most of the cases), so try using it instead (You said you're notifying the user anyway... So why can't you show the dialer instead of that notification?)

Comment: i am showing the dialer, that's why i wanted to avoid that permission description

Comment: Well, you don't need the permission then. `ACTION_DIAL` doesn't require any permission :)